# Is there any possibility to include *.pdb file into Release build to see error line number?

Tags: c#, msbuild, build, project, release

I made a project, all the settings are default.

When i run it in Debug mode (Build config = Debug) and face with exception - it dumps to my custom logging mechanism whith error line number, but when i run Release build - the same exception is logged without line number, only method throwing and call stack are logged.

Is there any possibility to enable detailed debug info in Release config (*.pdb files or smth.)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the Build tab (and when in the "Release" configuration), you can click Advanced... to change the Debug Info to "full", but note that this may make some compiler optimizations impossible.

Comment: I also get line numbers for exceptions when I set it to "pdb-only". That shouldn't hurt optimizations